# Access Form : Bind a recordset from sql server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, bind, recordset

I try to use again a code who whas successful on the past to bind a recordset from sql server to an Access Form.

```
Dim serverAddress As String, DB As String, stADO As String
serverAddress = "xxx" 
DB = "yyy"
stADO = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=" & serverAddress & ";Database=" & DB & ";UID=admin;PWD=password;"

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset
cn.ConnectionString = stADO

cn.Open

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Name", acFormDS

'sanity check if we have data on the Recordset
Debug.Print rs(2)

Set Forms("Form_Name").Form.Recordset = rs 
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

For sure the recorset is populate as debug.print rs(2) return a value.

When the command : "Set Forms("Form_Name").Form.Recordset = rs" is executed the database crashed and closed.

I have added also error management with on error goto but the DB crash without any message.

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide to resolve this issue.

Alexis

Error management without success
Use alternative connexion string
Test if the recordset is populated

Comment: Curious, why not use a linked table and a bound form? What is size of recordset in rows and columns being bounded?

Comment: Try with `Set Forms.Form_Name.Recordset = rs`. If the code is behind the form itself, replace with `Set Me.Recordset = rs`. But as advised above, no need to set the recordset this way - an unhanded error and it's gone.

Comment: @Parfait : i prefer direct connection instead of linked table to avoid create and ODBC.dsn fo each user of the application
I have tried with a recordset of 4 columns and 4 lines

Comment: @KostasK. : i will try this later today

Comment: @KostasK. no change on my issue. DB still crash

Comment: I am not sure I follow your reasoning regarding linked tables which are created one time. Ideally, you develop a *single* frontend app and send copies to users which does not require their own DSN.

Comment: To do so you need to save the DB password in clear and it's a security issue

Comment: Thanks guys for the time you took to help me on this subject.
I have found the reason why the DB crashed : it's because i had on the form a field with a sum. I have just deleted it and now it rocks ;-)